# Is using /file.php in an anchor link ALWAYS going to resolve to http://thedomain.com/file.php?

Tags: html

from my testing, this is true, but i just want to make sure it is a standard and not just coincidence that all browsers ive tested it in it works

basically, i have a page on

```
 http://domain.com/sub/dirs/1/2/3/page.htm
```

which has

```
<a href="/home.php">
```

will that always link to

```
http://domain.com/home.php
```

?

and of course will linking to `/sub/dirs/1/2/3/page.htm` link to itself (ie, link to http://domain.com/sub/dirs/1/2/3.htm) ??

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The leading `/` means that the link is relative to the top level domain name. Without a leading `/`, the link is relative to the same directory level as the page where the link appears.

[RFC 2396 (Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) contains the following in section 5:

> A relative reference beginning with a single slash character is termed an absolute-path reference, as defined by `<abs_path>` in Section 3.